# Multi user, allow user to read data and add their own data

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am trying to create a recipe database that can have many users. Each user can enter and save their own recipes, which only they have access to. The recipes are made up with various details including the ingredients that the recipe will use. The ingredients can come from 2 sources, the main 'read only' ingredient list provided by the app or from any 'custom' ingredients that the user has created (likely because the ingredient they wanted was not available in the list provided by the app). In each case the same information is stored about the ingredients (i.e. nutritional information etc.)

So a currently the schema looks something like:

**User**

- id
- name

**Recipe**

- id
- title
- userId

**RecipeIngredient**

- id
- ingredientId
- quantity
- recipeId
- userId

**Ingredient**

- id
- name
- nutritionalInfoId

**nutritionalInfo**

- id
- calories
- fat
- protein
- carbs

**Category**

- id
- name
- userId

**Recipe__Category**

- recipeId
- categoryId

What is the best way to handle this? I did start going down the route of adding a `UserIngredient` table:

**UserIngredient**

- id
- id
- name
- nutritionalInfoId
- userId

However, this made things more complicated when it came to assigning an ingredient to `RecipeIngredient` as it was either a relationship to `Ingredient` if the User had picked one of the apps 'built in' ingredients from the `Ingredient` table or one of their own from `UserIngredient`. It felt like there was probably a better way to handle this?

Comment: Is there an `ingredient` table per user? If not, how do you determine which ingredient belongs to whom?

Comment: The ‘ingredient’ table holds the main list of ingredients provided by the app, accessible by all users, however, these ingredients are read only to the users. Only an admin could CRUD them.

Comment: Then for each users own custom ingredients my first through was to save them in a single table, ‘UserIngredient’ and add a FK of the User.ID for the user that created that ingredient.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to model this, but I would choose a single `ingredient` table that contains all ingredients. Add a column `user_id` that is a foreign key to the table of users. Add a special "public" user (perhaps with `id` 0) that owns all the public ingredients.

Then you could create a unique constraint on `ingredient(id, user_id)` and reference that in the `recipeingredient` table. The only drawback is that you will need a *second* `user_id` column in `recipeingredient` that references `recipe(id, user_id)`. Perhaps call one user ID column `recipe_user_id` and the other `ingredient_user_id`.

Then it is easy to add a check constraint on `recipeingredient` that makes sure that `(recipe_user_id = ingredient_user_id OR ingredient_user_id = 0)`, so that nobody can use somebody else's private ingredients.